# Custom menus in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm way behind the curve when it comes to Office's "ribbon" approach to menus, but we're migrating an existing Access 2003 application to Access 2010. The custom menus that were created in the 2003 version imported fine, but I can't figure out how to edit them now that they're in 2010. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also applies to 2010 :

> "So, the choices you have for
>   modifying menu bars in 2007 are quite
>   limited. I suggest you either;
>
> a) use 2003 to change the menus 
>   b) use VBA code to modify the menus 
>   c) replace the menus with ribbons
>
> The above choices are not ideal.
>   However, there is no user graphical
>   interface in 2007 that lets you edit
>   menus graphically."

-- http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35479249/access-2007-how-to-edit.aspx

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the confirmation! Now, I learn about ribbons finally...